# Migration from silverlight 3 to silverlight 5

Tags: wcf, silverlight-5.0

Our application was developed with silverlight 3 now i want to migrate into the silverlight 5 version.

i am getting error in xaml. "Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives' that could not be found"

```
 <Style TargetType="controls:Calendar">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF8E8F8F"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CalendarButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarButton}"/>
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Calendar">
                <StackPanel x:Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <controlsPrimitives:CalendarItem x:Name="CalendarItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem}" IsEnabled="True" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: @gabe hope i am clear to you.

Comment: xmlns:controlsPrimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
this is the namespace reference.